# How to change text when Integer changes?

Tags: vb.net

I need some help with my Visual Basic application. I am coding a bingo game and I want to know how to trigger an event to change a label when the "score" Integer changes. Basically, I want to change the text of a label when the score is changed. This is my code so far:

```
Dim Integer score = 0
....
Private Sub OnScoreChange(sender As Integer, e As EventArgs) Handles score.{changed}
    ScoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + CStr(score) + " out of 15"
End Sub
```

If you need any more info just ask!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Where you setting/updating the value of score integer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly raise the event for variable changes - there's nothing in the language that implicitly does it for you.

Now, you haven't made it clear that the `score` variable and the event handler are in the same class or not.

Assuming that they are in the same class then there is no need for an event handler. You would write this kind of code:

```
Private _score As Integer = 0

Public Property Score() As Integer
    Get
        Return _score
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _score = Value
        Console.WriteLine("Score: " + CStr(_score) + " out of 15")
    End Set
End Property
```

Typically if you want to handle events you have two classes and you want one class to report value changes to any event handlers. In that case you'd write this code:

```
Public Class Bingo

    Public Event ScoreChange As EventHandler

    Private _score As Integer = 0

    Public Property Score() As Integer
        Get
            Return _score
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _score = Value
            RaiseEvent ScoreChange(Me, New EventArgs())
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

...and this in a separate class:

```
Private WithEvents _bingo As Bingo = New Bingo()

Private Sub ScoreChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _bingo.ScoreChange
    Console.WriteLine("Score: " + CStr(_bingo.Score) + " out of 15")
End Sub
```

Just as a quick aside, the naming convention for methods that handle events do not start with **`On`**. Methods that start with `On` are the methods that typically raise the event, not handle them. I called your handling method `ScoreChange` in line with this convention.

That's how to respond to changes in the value of `Score`.